# Fetch POST request not working properly as Entry is creating succesfully but payload is not being able to sent to the backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

**Problem Summary:** I have create a REST API for user registration in NodeJS on which I am trying to post the data from Front end using Fetch APIs. So when I am calling sending a Fetch POST method from front end the Payload is being sent to server but only 'id' is created. I think payload is not being sent properly from front end. Same thing when I am doing using POSTMAN I am able to POST the data successfully resulting the data entry to the DB.

**Code:**

**register.js**

```
class Forms extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: ""};
  }

  callAPI() {
    const URL = "http://localhost:4000/signup";
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      first_name: "Blank",
      last_name: "Blanco",
      email: "blank@meee.com",
      password: "passwoord123"
    });
    const otherParam = {
      mode: "cors",
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: data,
      method: "POST",
    }
    fetch(URL,otherParam)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    /* fetch.post("http://localhost:4000/signup")       // GET is working properly
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }))
          .catch(err => err); */
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }
}
```

**signup.js** // POST request from Backend using Express Router

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  const signup = new Signup({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  signup
    .save()
    .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Handling POST requests to /signup",
      received_data: result
    });
  })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  });
});
```

What is wrong in this Code? Can someone help along with some explanatrion about what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Which packages you are using to parse json in the backend?

Comment: I am using bodyParser to parse json, mongoose for ORM and DB is MongoDB, express for routing

Comment: try printing `req` and let us know whats the data init when hit from frontend

Comment: print req.body from backend end see, either your data is parsed or not as expected.

Comment: I am getting blank json object
{}
{ __v: 0, _id: 5cc940abce6e51521cd939a1 }
POST /signup 201 319.250 ms - 106

Comment: why are you posting to ".../signup" but listening to "/"?

Comment: what do you mean listing to "/"?

Comment: listening** const URL = "http://localhost:4000/signup"; and router.post("/",

Comment: Yes about that is I am listening the server on localhost:4000 and sending the request from localhost:3000

Comment: am not talking about the host, am saying that your routes are different.. shouldn't be router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) ... ?

Comment: no actually I have already created routes for signup and login, So It is already working behing as /signup
// Routes which should handle requests
app.use("/signup", signupRoutes);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because of a `typo` if your `fetch` options. It should be `headers` not `header`

```
const otherParam = {
  mode: "cors",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: data,
  method: "POST",
}
```